# cpack deb generator components output names

Tags: c++, c, cmake, debian, cpack

```
install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_shared DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib 
    COMPONENT runtime)
install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}_static DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib 
    COMPONENT development)
install (FILES ${INCLUDES} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
    COMPONENT development)

...
set (CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME 
    "lib${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}_${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}_${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE}")
```

I have 2 deb packages as a result:

```
libmpreal_0.1.1-1_amd64-development.deb
libmpreal_0.1.1-1_amd64-runtime.deb
```

But I want to have for debian standarts another names:

```
libmpreal-dev_0.1.1-1_amd64.deb
libmpreal_0.1.1-1_amd64.deb
```

Now I am reading [this](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/CPack/cmCPackDebGenerator.cxx) at the method **cmCPackDebGenerator::PackageOnePack**
here is a code:

```
outputFileName(
    std::string(this->GetOption("CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME")) 
    + "-" + packageName + this->GetOutputExtension()
);
```

Does this mean that I cant specify a name for my packages?! I would like to make a mistake..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming scheme for CPack generated package is not flexible enough to do what 
you want, there is a pending bug/feature request for that, [bug 12997](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/12997),
along with a bunch of related bug report.

Short answer is: you can't do what you want now.